# Adaboost Training Error and It's Trend

Tags: svm, adaboost

The Adaboost M1 algorithm is as follows:

> $\mathbf{Input}$: sequence of m examples $<(x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m)>$
>   with the labels $y_i \in Y = \{1,...,k\}$
>   weak learning algorithm WeakLearn
>   integer T specifying the number of iterations
>   $\mathbf{Initialize}$: $D_i(i) = \frac{1}{m}$ for all i
>   $\mathbf{Do}$ t = 1,2,...,T:
>   1. Call WeakLearn, providing it with distribution $D_t$
>   2. Get back a hypothesis $h_t : X \rightarrow Y$
>   3. Calculate the error of $\displaystyle h_t: \epsilon_t = \sum_{i:h_t(x_i)\neq y_i} D_i(i)$
>   If $\epsilon_t > 0.5$, then set $T = t - 1$ and abort loop.
>   4. $\displaystyle \beta_t = \frac{\epsilon_t}{1-\epsilon_t}$
>   5. Update distribution $D_t$ as $\displaystyle D_{t+1} = \frac{D_t(i)}{Z_t} \times \begin{cases}
> \beta_t,  & \text{if $h_t(x_i) = y_i$} \\
> 1, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases} $
>   where $Z_t$ is a normalization constant (chosen so that $D_{t+1}$ will be a distribution)

Someone explained to me that the error, $\epsilon_t$ would decrease as the algorithm iterates. However, this does not make sense to me.

I am using an SVM as a WeakClassifier and training on samples drawn from $X$, based on each samples weights. This makes SVM a weak classifier.

Now assume that $\epsilon_t$ is 0.23. This means that $\beta_t$ is 0.29. To update the distribution, I multiply the correctly classified sample's weights by $\beta_t$ and leave the incorrectly classified samples weights unchanged. Now note the fact that I have to normalize the distribution, the distribution at this stage must be less than a sum of 1.0 (because we only decrease some weights and leave others unchanged).

Now, when I have to normalize this new distribution with $Z_t$, which is the sum of $D_t$ and so less than 1.0. Hence, I increase all the weights in the distribution. However, since it is a distribution only the relative weights matter.

However, when I compute the weighted error $\epsilon_t$, then it won't be less than the previous iteration necessarily - simply because all the weights have increased in absolute terms.

Since the weight increases, I end up ending the loop very early sometimes.  Does the above analysis make sense or am I missing an important detail?

Comment: I believe it would just be the unweighted training error that will decrease.

Comment: @MatthewDrury How would I compute that? Just add all the missclassified instances I imagine. In addition, the stopping condition is based on the weighted error. My issue is that the classifier just stops way too early.

Comment: I'm not really sure, I never invested much time into understanding AdaBoost.  I suppose I should ask, what's this for, just education?  It's not very common to use AdaBoost these days for any real machine learning work.  Gradient Boosting tends to just be better across the board.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Yes, for education.